# How do apps in android update their data without updating the whole app itself?

Tags: android

I am new to android app developing, I just wanna know the basic tools required to make an app.
Also please tell me how some apps like flipboard etc. update their contents without updating the whole app itself.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way of asking a question so please make sure you read the rules first. This is not a programming question and it is way to broad, you should Google this kind of question and not ask it on stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
how some apps like flipboard etc. update their contents without updating the whole app itself.
```

They get their data from the internet, so their main database is in the server on the internet not in the apps. Hence, the applicaton it self is not updated, because the code is still same, only the data (taken from internet) changed.

To get the data from internet, you will need a web service (using REST or SOAP) and a server/hosting. For beginning, i suggest you to use XAMPP (apache + mySql) and using REST as web service.

Answer (score -1):

For developing android app you can use `android-studio`, It is google recommended IDE for android development. Also you can checkout this link for tips [android cliffnotes](https://guides.codepath.com/android).

Comment: How is this even an answer for this question?

Comment: Shivam also mentioned about tools for android development and I gave him a links since he is new in android. Just trying to be helpful that's it!